# Example: Lie group compact, abelian and disconnected.

Tags: lie-groups

I'm looking for a example of a Lie group compact, abelian and disconnected, such that exist some elements $x$, where $x^n\neq e, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you try some subset of $O(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: O(n,$\mathbb{R}$) is a compact Lie group, it has two connected components. So, can you find some abelian subset of it?

Answer (score 6):

Try irrational rotations in $U(1)\times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. It forms such an example:

- It is the product of two abelian groups, hence abelian
- Topologically, it is a disjoint union of two copies of $S^1$, hence compact and disconnected
- Irrational rotations give infinite cyclic subgroups

Comment: Is this a answer?

Comment: @CristyanPinheiro Yes. :)

Comment: Is the $\mathbb Z_2$ meant to be integers-mod-2, or 2-adic integers? If the former, which seems to be suggested by the second bullet point, I'd be confused about how irrational rotations are essentially different from irrational rotations in a single circle, in the first place, and how the topology avoids being just that of $\mathbb Z$, etc. Please clarify the intent? Thanks!

Comment: @paulgarrett $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is indeed $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The irrational rotations aren't essentially different from irrational rotations in a single circle, but the OP asked for a disconnected group. The topology is just a disjoint union of two circles. (It's an uncountable set, so cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.) Does this help clarify?

Comment: Thanks, @Neal, and now as I reread the question, I see that it is asking for much less than what I'd (mis-) understood. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal group $O(2,\mathbb{R})$ answers the question.